# Bind observable array using AJAX inside function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'am using Knockout.js. I have a function like this:

```
function deviceGroupItem(item) {
    this.DeviceGroupName = item.DeviceGroupName;
    this.groupDevicesVisible = ko.observable(false)
    this.groupDevicesArray = ko.observableArray();
    this.deviceGroupClick = function () {
        if (this.groupDevicesVisible() == false) {
            this.groupDevicesVisible(true)
            $.ajax({
                url: returnServer() + '/api/Mobile/getRoomDevices?accessToken=' + localStorage.getItem('Token'),
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    this.groupDevicesArray()($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return new roomDeviceItem(item);
                    }))
                },
                error: function () {

                }
            })
        } else {
            this.groupDevicesVisible(false)
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

Problem is, when I'am trying bind:

```
this.groupDevicesArray = ko.observableArray();
```

Using:

```
this.groupDevicesArray()($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return new roomDeviceItem(item);
                    }))
```

I'am receiving error "this.groupDevicesArray is not a function". Honestly, I dont know how to do this in correct way. Do You know how can I achieve that?

Comment: Try this : 
    this.groupDevicesArray (ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(item) {
       return new roomDeviceItem(item);
    });   or  this.groupDevicesArray($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return new roomDeviceItem(item);
                    }))

Comment: Thank You for answer, but still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of you referring observable Array with `this` inside the function `deviceGroupClick` which does not exist because `this` refers to current context .

> `This` technique depends on current closure which is a pseudo variable
>   that may differ from scope to scope dynamically .

**viewModel:**

```
function roomDeviceItem(data) {
    this.room = ko.observable(data.room)
}

function deviceGroupItem() {
    var self=this; //Assign this to self & use self everywhere
    self.groupDevicesArray = ko.observableArray();
    self.deviceGroupClick = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/json/',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                data = [{
                    'room': 'One'
                }, {
                    'room': 'Two'
                }]
                self.groupDevicesArray($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return new roomDeviceItem(item);
                }))
            }
        });
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new deviceGroupItem());
```

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26527/)**

Just in-case if you are looking for solution with `this` you need to use `bind(this)` to get reference of outer closure check **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26528/)**

Comment: I found a solution, but this also works, so thank You for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.groupDevicesArray($.map(data, function (item) {
  return new roomDeviceItem(item);
}));
```

`groupDevicesArray` is observableArray and `$.map` returns an array.

Comment: Thank You for answer, but problem is still the same.

Comment: jsfiddle would help then.